# An analogue of Mostow-Palais equivariant embedding theorem for the group of conformal automorphisms of the 2-sphere

Tags: lie-groups, group-actions

Is there a smooth embedding of $S^2$ into some Euclidean space that is equivariant with respect to a linear representation of $PSL(2,\mathbb C)$?
A counterexample to a more general question can be found [here.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/149867/is-there-an-analogue-of-mostow-palais-equivariant-embedding-theorem-for-noncompa)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is 'no'.  In fact, a stronger statement is true: If $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space and $G\subset\mathrm{GL}(V)$ is a (connected) non-compact simple Lie group, then the only bounded orbits of $G$ are fixed points. *A fortiori*, the only compact $G$-orbits are fixed points.

To see this, it's enough to prove it for $G = \mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$, since every connected non-compact simple Lie group contains a copy of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ (or its quotient $\mathrm{SO}(2,1)$).

Moreover, it is enough to prove the claim when $V$ is an irreducible representation of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$, so assume that. Thus, $V = S^d(W)$ where $W\simeq\mathbb{R}^2$ is the standard $2$-dimensional representation of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$, with basis elements $x$ and $y$.  The diagonal subgroup of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$, a copy of $\mathbb{R}^\times$, acts on $x$ and $y$ as $r \cdot x = rx$ and $r\cdot y = r^{-1}y$ for $r\in\mathbb{R}^\times$.  An element of $S^d(W)$ is a polynomial in $x$ and $y$, homogeneous of degree $d$, and we have $r\cdot (x^k y^{d-k}) = r^{2k-d} x^k y^{d-k}$.  Thus, the only element of $S^d(W)$ that could have a bounded $G$-orbit would be $x^{d/2}y^{d/2}$ (and that exists only when $d$ is even).  However, unless $d=0$, the element $(xy)^{d/2}$ (when it exists) has its $G$-orbit containing polynomials that are not multiples of $(xy)^{d/2}$, and hence their $G$-orbits are not bounded, so the $G$-orbit of $(xy)^{d/2}$ is not bounded either.

Comment: Many thanks! Now that I know what to look for I found a more general result in Lemma 4 of Dani's "Dense Orbits of Affine Automorphisms and Compactness of Groups" where it is shown that if a linear real representation of a connected Lie group $G$ has a bounded orbit that isn't a point, then the quotient of $G$ by its center is compact. The proof is a reduction to the case of a noncompact simple subgroup for which (according to Dani) the answer is well-known. Thank you for explaining why.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek:  I'm not surprised that it's well-known; the proof is so simple.  I didn't know where to look for a reference, though, so I just wrote down a proof.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek:  By the way, if you are satisfied with my answer, you should probably go ahead and accept it, so that it won't keep being brought up periodically (because it doesn't have an accepted answer).

Comment: Actually, I misquoted Dani's lemma 4. He also assumes that the group acts freely on the bounded orbit. So lemma 4 does not formally imply or subsume your argument. But the part of the proof about a noncompact simple Lie group survives.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek:  Maybe I misunderstood your first comment, but when you wrote that "The proof is a reduction to the case of a noncompact simple subgroup for which (according to Dani) the answer is well-known", I thought you were insinuating that Dani didn't actually give a proof (or reference) for the case of a noncompact simple subgroup, he just claimed it was 'well known'.  Is that the case?

Comment: Here is quote from Dini's paper, lemma 4: "It is well known that under any finite dimensional representation $\tau$ any bounded orbit of a non-compact simple Lie group $S$ is a singleton set. (If $\tau(S)$ is non-trivial, it is generated by its unipotent elements; this yields a proof of the assertion.)". Nothing more is said.